# Volume not appearing in Finder -> Devices

Tags: macos, finder

I have a SD card that's mounting but not appearing in Finder's sidebar under devices.

I've tried running `chflags nohidden /Volumes/SMICROSD/` in terminal but the volume does not appear in the sidebar.

Other volumes appear in the Finder sidebar under devices when they are mounted.

I borrowed a USB SD card reader and the volume populates Finder's Sidebar when installed through that. It is mounting but not appearing in Finder -> Devices when installed into the Mac's builtin SD card reader.

OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Is there data you need on that card? Does it show up in Disk Utility? Can you then format the card using Disk Utility? I have seen this behavior with removable devices (thumb drives, SD cards, etc.) and if you format them on the Mac that *sometimes* fixes the "won't mount" problem.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yeah there's data I need on that card. It shows up in disk utility. It mounts, but it isn't appearing in Devices on Finder: I can open /Volumes and see it there